# Non-Japanese hot springs near Sydney

Tags: australia, culture, day-trips, sydney, hot-springs

I can find a Japanese-style hot spring near Sydney. In the Blue Mountains, there's [Japanese Bath House](http://www.japanesebathhouse.com.au/), which according to [visitnsw](http://www.visitnsw.com/destinations/blue-mountains/lithgow-area/lithgow/attractions/japanese-bath-house-blue-mountains) is "the only Japanese onsen (hot spring) in New South Wales where you can experience the Japanese spa culture."

However, are there any non-Japanese hot springs within day-trip distance of Sydney? Any non-Japanese style is ok, so for example a Turkish-style hot spring would be ok. Australian-style, if there's such a thing, would be an added bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of, depending on what you're expecting.

There aren't many (any?) natural hot springs within day trip distance of Sydney.  To get to natural hot water supplies, you'll have to travel to [above the Artesian Basin](http://pretraveller.com/2013/06/09/australian-artesian-hot-springs/) (six hours drive one-way) or [more further afield](https://au.totaltravel.yahoo.com/travel-ideas/news-opinions/news/a/-/16643113/australia-s-best-hot-springs/).

However spa resorts and day spas have become a big thing in Australia, from [the truly luxuriant](http://www.wolganvalley.com/wolgan-valley/en/resort/spa-fitness/) [on](https://www.lilianfels.com.au/day-spa) [down](http://www.sebelhawkesbury.com.au/spa.html) and many of these are within day trip range of Sydney.

So depending upon what your aim is - getting a hot spring experience, visiting an actual hot spring or something else - there may be something to fill the criteria.